# ServiceLocator does not exist in Ninject?

Tags: ninject

I am trying to use Ninject with Common Service Locator in my asp.net mvc3 project. I've added `Ninject.dll` and `CommonServiceLocator.NinjectAdapter.dll` to the project.

I wrote following code in my global.asax.cs file.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
   ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new NinjectServiceLocator(CreateKernel()));
   RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
   RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

private static IKernel CreateKernel()
{
   IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
   kernel.Bind(typeof(IUserService)).To(typeof(UserService));
   return kernel;
}
```

But it does not compile because it couldn't find `ServiceLocator` and giving me the error

```
"The name 'ServiceLocator' does not exist in the current context"
```

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing a reference?

Answer (score 4):

I think you won't get an answer to your question because using the Common ServiceLocator is very uncommon especially for MVC3. The service locator anti-pattern you seem to use is considered bad practice.

Almost everyone is using some IDependencyResolver implementation instead. See https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/MVC3